# How to improve sub-matrix-vector multiplication c code

Tags: c, linear-algebra, numerical-computing

I have C code for generic-sub-matrix-vector (gesubmv) multiplication that computes
**y(rinds) = A(rinds, cinds)*x(cinds) + y(rinds)**, where rinds and cinds are vectors of row and column (not necessarily sorted) indices, respectively. For genericity, **rinds = rindsA_data(rindsA_1:rindsA_m)** and **cindsA_data(cindsA_1:cindsA_n)**.

My code is the following:

```
void gesubmv(const double A_data[], const int A_size[2],
             const int rindsA_data[], int rindsA_1, int rindsA_m,
             const int cindsA_data[], int cindsA_1, int cindsA_n,
             const double x_data[], double y_data[]) {
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = rindsA_1; i <= rindsA_m; i++) {
        int k;
        double tmp_sum;
        tmp_sum = 0.0F;
        for (j = cindsA_1; j <= cindsA_n; j++) {
            k = cindsA_data[j - 1] - 1;
            tmp_sum +=
                x_data[k] * A_data[k + (A_size[1] * (rindsA_data[i - 1] - 1))];
        }
        k = rindsA_data[i - 1] - 1;
        y_data[k] += tmp_sum;
    }
}
```

The issue is that it seems to be more efficient to compute **y(:) = A(:, cinds)*x(cinds) + y(:)** and then pick **y(rinds)**. I suspect this might be related to how instructions are performed (https://godbolt.org/). Or I could do something (more obvious) wrong. Any ideas?

Code for the alternative **y(:) = A(:, cinds)*x(cinds) + y(:)** is the following.

```
void gesubmv2(const double A_data[], const int A_size[2],
             const int cindsA_data[], int cindsA_1, int cindsA_n,
             const double x_data[], double y_data[]) {
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < A_size[1]; i++) {
        int k;
        double tmp_sum;
        tmp_sum = 0.0F;
        for (j = cindsA_1; j <= cindsA_n; j++) {
            k = cindsA_data[j - 1] - 1;
            tmp_sum += x_data[k] * A_data[k + (A_size[1] * i)];
        }
        y_data[i] += tmp_sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this code works, but you're looking for optimizations, probably a better candidate for [code review exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The performance of this code can be greatly affected by the sizes of the arrays, the relationship of `A_size[1]` to the cache geometry, the ordering of values in `rindsA_data` and `cindsA_data`, the locations of the arrays relative to each other, and features of the target platform. Without that information, it is hard to say how to optimize the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the (A_size[1] * (rindsA_data[i - 1] - 1)) expression out of the j loop. The optimiser might be doing this already so you might not see much if any performance difference. Likewise, in the second snippet, (A_size[1] * i) doesn't need to be inside the j loop. If your optimiser isn't doing as I suggested, this could be why you're seeing the performance difference.

Also, you increment j with the for statement, then use j-1 as an index, so you can save one operation by putting the k assignmet once before the loop and once after you've calculated tmp_sum. e.g.

```
    kk = (A_size[1] * (rindsA_data[i - 1] - 1));
    k = cindsA_data[cindsA_1 - 1] - 1;
    for (j = cindsA_1; j < cindsA_n; j++) {
        tmp_sum +=
            x_data[k] * A_data[k + kk];
        k = cindsA_data[j] - 1;
    }
    tmp_sum += x_data[k] * A_data[k + kk];
```